# How can I reuse same "Content Controller" in different tab (child) in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I have a TabControl in a XAML file like this:

```
<UserControl d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">    
    <TabControl Style="{DynamicResource WizardTabControlStyle}">
        <TabItem >
            <local:Tab1/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <local:Tab2/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <local:Tab3/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

and every tab is defined in another xaml file:

```
<UserControl d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="794">
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Model1}">
    <GroupBox Header="{concept:Intl Key=Geometry, DefaultText='G1'}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="165"> 
        <Grid>
           // Common view
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <GroupBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Header="{concept:Intl Key=G2, DefaultText='G2'}" DataContext="{Binding G2}" Padding="0,10">
        <Grid>
           // other stuff
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Other tab views are the same as this.

What I want to do is that define a graphical view (OpenGL) in the TabControl and then in the single tab XAML, I want a reference to that view. Every tab sin the "//Common view" should have the same OpenGL view defined in the Tab Control.

Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly is the graphical/common view? Can't you define it as a UserControl like you do with the tabs?

Comment: can u do it with `VisualBrush` ?

Comment: @mm8 I want to add a graphical view , which will be the same for every tab. I am new to XAMl so little bit messed up.

Comment: @Vannian: You didn't answer my question. What exactly is this "graphical view"?

Comment: @mm8 it is a ContentControl Binding to OpenGL class, which will show the 3d engine in that place.

Comment: So move the ContentControl to a UserControl and just add an instance of the UserControl to the Grid; `<local:YourUserControl />`.